# How to find out superclass in an annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm building an annotation processor. How can I find out the superclass of an annotated class?

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@Target({ METHOD, TYPE })
public @interface Auditable {
}

class A {
    @Auditable
    Integer getInt() { ... }
}

@Auditable
class B extends A { ... }
```

Annotation processor provides two annotated elements. One for method `getInt` in class A and one for class B.

How can I find out that B extends A?

Partial code of the annotation processor:

```
private void process( Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv ) {
    Set<? extends Element> annotatedElements =
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith( Auditable.class );
    for ( Element element : annotatedElements ) {
        ElementKind kind = element.getKind();
        if ( ElementKind.CLASS.equals( kind ) ) {
            // --- here I need to find out superclass ---
        } else if ( ElementKind.METHOD.equals( kind ) ) {
            workOnMethod( (ExecutableElement) element );
        } else {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage( Kind.WARNING,
                String.format( "WARNING: @Auditable must be applied "
                "to a JPA entity or method but found at %s", element.toString()));
        }}}
```

Comment: if `element` has kind of `javax.lang.model.util.ElementFilter#TYPE_KINDS` you may cast it to `TypeElement` which in turn has `getSuperclass` method

Comment: Casting element just to TypeElement does the trick!